# Kafka Connect - Transformes rename field only if it exist

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have an S3 sink connector for multiple topics (topic_a, topic_b, topic_c) and topic_a have field creat**ed**_date and topic_b, topic_c have creati**on**_date . I have used the below `transforms.RenameField.renames` to rename the field (creat**ed**_date:creati**on**_date) but since the only topic_a have created_date and others don't, the connector is failing.

I want to move all the messages (from all topics with single connector) into s3 with creation_date (and rename created_date to creation_date if exist) but I am not able to figure out the regex or transformer to rename the field (if it exists) for the specific topic.

```
   "config":{
      "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
      "errors.log.include.messages":"true",
      "s3.region":"eu-west-1",
      "topics.dir":"dir",
      "flush.size":"5",
      "tasks.max":"2",
      "s3.part.size":"5242880",
      "timezone":"UTC",
      "locale":"en",
      "format.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
      "errors.log.enable":"true",
      "s3.bucket.name":"bucket",
      "topics": "topic_a, topic_b, topic_c",
      "s3.compression.type":"gzip",
      "partitioner.class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DailyPartitioner",
      "name":"NAME",
      "storage.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
      "key.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
      "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
      "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
      "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
      "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"https://schemaregistry.com",
      "enhanced.avro.schema.support": "true",
      "transforms": "RenameField",
      "transforms.RenameField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
      "transforms.RenameField.renames": "created_date:creation_date"
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only topic_a have created_date and others don't,

Then you would use separate Connectors. One with the Transform and all topics with the field, then another without the transform.

> from all topics with single connector

This doesn't scale very well. You're making limited consumer threads and one consumer group to read from many topics at once. Multiple connectors would be better to distribute the load.

Comment: Thank you @onecricketeer, I understand that the best solution is to create separate connectors but there is not much load to distribute that's why I am looking for one connector. Do you have any thoughts to rename the field if it exist else copy the message as it is.

Comment: Unfortunately connect itself cannot easily do such logic. You'd have to write KStreams to do something at that level

Comment: Thank you, I have ended up with separate connectors for ease topic.